# How to pass XmlDocument to post method in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xmldocument

I have a web api post method as:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("LoggerAttachment")]
    public string PostLoggerAttachment([FromBody] XmlDocument doc)
    {
        if (doc == null)
            return "Data is empty";
    }
```

How can I pass `XmlDocument doc` to this method using `PostAsXmlAsync`?
I tried every thing including:

```
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync(apiUrl, doc);
```

Non of them working.

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: It causes error. when I change it to "await client.PostAsXmlAsync(apiUrl, doc.InnerXml)" it works but variable for "PostLoggerAttachment([FromBody] string docxml)" is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong. I should use `PostAsJsonAsync` instead of `PostAsXmlAsync`. So the following line works for me:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<XmlDocument>(apiUrl, doc);
```